# The trait `FromSql<'_>` is not implemented for `Uuid` in tokio-postgres in rust

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-tokio, tokio-postgres

**I am trying to use UUID as my primary key in Postgres.**

I am getting *the trait `FromSql<'_>` is not implemented for `Uuid` in tokio-postgres*.

First I try to use `tokio-pg-mapper` but it is also showing the same compile error.

So, I try diff approach and try to implement the From on Struct to covert it directly from Row.

When I try to implements `From` to convert the `Row` type to my struct `Shop`.

```
impl From<Row> for Shop {
    fn from(row: Row) -> Self {
       Self {
            id: row.get("id"), // Id is UUID type
            name: row.get("name"),
            address: row.get("address")
       }
    }
}
```

Still getting the *the trait `FromSql<'_>` is not implemented for `Uuid` in tokio-postgres*

> I know that it is asking me to implement the `FromSql` for the `UUID` type.
> But I looked into the `tokio-postgres` [docs](https://docs.rs/tokio-postgres/0.7.2/tokio_postgres/types/trait.FromSql.html#impl-FromSql%3C%27a%3E-for-Uuid) and found that it is already implemented there.

**Did I miss something ?**

`uuid=0.8`
`tokio-postgres=0.7.2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To activate the `UUID` support I need to declare it in my `Cargo.toml` file and it will start working with `tokio-pg-mapper` and with my custom solution too.

```
tokio-postgres = {version="0.7.2", features=["with-uuid-0_8"]}
```